# Extracting RAR files in a directory

Tags: python, beginner, compression

I just started programming, and something is telling me that this working function looks to big for what it does. Can you give a better version of the code so I can understand how to code faster, shorter code ?

```
import os, rarfile

xpath= "/root/tree/def/"

dpath="/root/tree/down"

def unrar():
        for rf in os.listdir(dpath):
            f = os.path.join(dpath,rf)
            o = rarfile.RarFile(f)
            for u in o.infolist():
             print (u.filename, u.file_size)
             o.extractall(xpath)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use more descriptive names than `f`, `o`, `u` and `rf`. It makes your code harder to read, even if it's all quite small and contained.

```
def unrar():
    for rar in os.listdir(dpath):
        filepath = os.path.join(dpath, rar)
        opened_rar = rarfile.RarFile(filepath)
        for f in opened_rar.infolist():
            print (f.filename, f.file_size)
        opened_rar.extractall(xpath)
```

Note that I still use `f` for the files you iterate over in the `opened_rar`, because single letter variables are occasionally ok. Especially in limited contexts, where they're commonly used (`f` will often refer to a file when iterating). But using multiple ones together can easily be confusing and less readable.

Your function should also take `xpath` and `dpath` as parameters, rather than using constants. This makes it easier to reuse the function and have it run on different files or in different places, rather than having to manually change the constant values. It's also easy to change:

```
def unrar(dpath, xpath):
```

And then just call it with:

```
unrar(dpath, xpath)
```

Also Python has a great tool called context managers. These will basically ensure that your file is always closed no matter what happens. Every time you open a file with Python it needs to be closed again. And you actually never closed yours, so it's better practice to use a context manager, like this:

```
def unrar(dpath, xpath):
    for rar in os.listdir(dpath):
        filepath = os.path.join(dpath, rar)
        with rarfile.RarFile(filepath) as opened_rar:
            for f in opened_rar.infolist():
                print (f.filename, f.file_size)
            opened_rar.extractall(xpath)
```

Everything inside the `with` block is now what happens with the `opened_rar` file. Once you exit that block, the file is *always* closed. Crucially, this holds true even if an error causes your script to end prematurely. I haven't worked with rar files, but I can tell you that when using zip files you can lose your data by having errors interrupt your script. A context manager prevents this data loss, making it safer.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to context managers ! This is definitely going to be really useful when working with opened files. I have recently switched to a more advanced Vim configuration with support for python3 with better indentation and highlighting for whitespaces, etc. I have one more question : Why should I call the function with parameters the function is already catching and using dpath and xpath without including them as parameters ? To my understanding, any function on this python script will be able to use these constants.

Comment: @xavier Glad to help! Context managers have really done a lot for me. The parameters suggestion is for the sake of making code reusable. If those are constants across multiple functions then it would make sense to have them as they are now, though if you name them `DPATH` and `XPATH` it'll be clearer that they're constants.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mis-reading, this:

```
        for u in o.infolist():
         print (u.filename, u.file_size)
         o.extractall(xpath)
```

...is re-extracting the RAR file once for every file it contains. I think you probably wanted:

```
for u in o.infolist():
    print (u.filename, u.file_size)
o.extractall(xpath)
```

So you print out information for each contained file, then extract all of the files once.

Comment: Furthermore, the narrow and haphazard indentation was probably a contributing factor to this bug. Four spaces per level is the standard, according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: ok, I see that. I am using Vim 7.4 with compiled support for Python. I was expecting the indentation problem to be solved.